# C# - 'Double' is an ambiguous reference

Tags: c#, case-sensitive, disambiguation

I have the following files in my code base:

**StandardUnits.Numbers.Double**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StandardUnits.Numbers
{
    public class Double : Number<double>
    {
        public Double(double value) : base(value) { }
        public static implicit operator Double(double value) { return new Double(value); }
        public static implicit operator double(Double value) { return value._value; }
    }
}
```

and

**StandardUnitsTest.Program**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using StandardUnits;
using StandardUnits.Numbers;

namespace StandardUnitsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Equatable<string> str = "Hello! This is my number: ";
            Number<float> n = 4;
            Double o = 5.5;
            Float p = n + o;

            Console.WriteLine(str + p.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, using "Double" produces the following error:

```
Error 1 'Double' is an ambiguous reference between 'double' and 'StandardUnits.Numbers.Double' 16 13
```

But no such error is produced for "Float", which is made in an identical fashion to "Double" (but with "float" instead of "double", obviously). Why is the compiler able to distinguish between `StandardUnits.Numbers.Float` and `float`, but not between `StandardUnits.Numbers.Double` and `double`? Why is case sensitivity not preventing this?

I can provide code snippets for Number and Float as well, if desired.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a conflict with [System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

There is no System.Float (`float` is represented by [System.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) instead), hence no conflict.

Answer (score 9):

The CLR type for `double` is [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx). That's the ambiguity.

The CLR type for `float` is [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx). That's not ambiguous with your `Float` type... although it does suggest that your type should be named `Single` instead, for consistency with the framework. Ideally change the names so they *don't* conflict with types in the `System` namespace though... assuming you *really* need these types at all. (What benefits are they adding?)

This does *not* have anything to do with the `float` and `double` aliases in C# and case-sensitivity, really. Those are just hard-wired aliases for `System.Single` and `System.Double` respectively, and would never be ambiguous. It's your use of `Double` which is ambiguous.

Comment: To address your question: firstly, I wasn't aware that System offered these structures to begin with (or, rather, that its primitives are aliases for these structures). Secondly, System.Single and System.Double are structs; I'm going for classes. Thirdly, they specify my custom class (Number) whose behavior I'd like to inherit.

Answer (score 2):

System.Double already exists (it's built into the language.) I'm curious as to why you're creating your own version.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx

Comment: Ignorance. I first tried to make "Float", and realized it didn't exist, so I made my own. Then tried the same with "Double". ;)

Comment: No worries. I once made my own string class. Much worse.

Comment: Also, my own is a wrapper that inherits from a generic "Numbers" wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is a [`System.Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) type (its alias is `double`) but no `System.Float`: it's called [`System.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) - its alias is `float`.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a `Double` class in the `System` namespace (`double` is an alias for it), so if you use `Double`, the compiler doesn't know which one you meant.

However, `float` is an alias for `System.Single`. There is no `System.Float`, so there is no conflict.

See ["Built-in Types"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).